# Construction is functorial?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was trying to prove that the degree of the suspension $\Sigma f$ of a map $f: S^n \longrightarrow S^n$ is the same as the degree of $f$.
I used Mayer-Vietoris to obtain the following diagram:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 H_{n+1}(\Sigma S^n) @>{(\Sigma f)_*}>> H_{n+1}(\Sigma S^n) \\ @V\partial VV @VV{\partial}V \\  H_n(S^n) @>>{f_*}>  H_n(S^n) \end{CD}
$$

Where $\partial$ is the connecting homomorphism in the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Intuitively this diagram should commute and the claim follows directly from this. However, I am struggling to conclude that the diagram commutes. I read somewhere that the "construction is functorial, so the diagram commutes", but what does this mean exactly?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

The statement is that the suspension isomorphism is natural (in the sense of category theory), see e.g. [this mathstacksexchange post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841488/natural-isomorphism-tilde-h-ix-xrightarrow-cong-tilde-h-i1-sigma-x). You can of course also find this statement in most books on algebraic topology, such as Hatcher's book.